# How to calculate Modulo using a standard calculator for a one time pad encryption

Tags: one-time-pad, modular-arithmetic

I wrote a simple python script to preform one time pad encryption 
I would like to be able to decrypt the ciphertext by hand. In my script I use mod 26.

This is how I was shown to calculate a mod using a calculator:

- 467%26 = 25
- 467/26 = 17.9615...
- 17*26=442
- 467-442=25

I used this code to preform the one time pad in my script

```
ciphertext = plaintext+key%26
plaintext =  ciphertext-key%26
```

I’m using CT-46 to convert letters to numbers

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|  A    E    I    N    O    R    |      CT-46       |
|  1    2    3    4    5    6    |                  |
|---------------------------------------------------|
|  B    C    D    F    G    H    J    K    L    M   |
|  70   71   72   73   74   75   76   77   78   79  |
|---------------------------------------------------|
|  P    Q    S    T    U    V    W    X    Y    Z   |
|  80   81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89  |
|---------------------------------------------------|
|  SPC  .    ,    :    ?    /    (    )    "  CODE  |
|  90   91   92   93   94   95   96   97   98   99  |
|---------------------------------------------------|
|  0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   |
|  00   01   02   03   04   05   06   07   08   09  |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

- plaintext = tavares -> CT-46 chart-> 83,1,85,1,6,2,82
- the key is 48,5,03,1,9,3,25
- ciphertext = 105,6,88,2,15,5,107

To decrypt the ciphertext you would do this in python:

```
105-48%26 = 83 that is T on the CT-46 chart
```

Now if I try to decrypt by hand using a calculator, this is what I get:

- 105-48=57
- 57/26 = 2.1923076923076923076923076923077
- 2*26=52
- 57-52=5

The Difference should be `83`, not `5`. What is it that I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### a bit of history

Historically, [one-time pads](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cryptography/One_time_pads) written on paper were almost invariably one of two types: "alphabetic" or "decimal".
CT-46 is one type of [straddling checkerboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/straddling_checkerboard) encoding -- but CT-46 assumes you are using a decimal one-time pad.

- Alphabetic ("base 26"): the key pad has groups of 5 alphabetic letters 'A' through 'Z'. Using these pads requires using "modulo 26". Each letter on an alphabetic key pad should be generated with a 1/26 chance to be any particular letter.
- Decimal ("base 10"): The key pad has groups of 5 decimal digits '0' through '9'. Using these pads requires using "modulo 10". Decimal one-time pads also require some "encoding" for converting each letter in the message into decimal digits. Each digit on a decimal key pad should be generated with a 1/10 chance to be any particular digit.

The "[/dev/random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random)" is a good source of random values that you can convert into a one-time pad -- a series of alphabetic letters -- or a series of decimal digits.
My understanding is that python uses that source for [ssl.RAND_bytes()](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/ssl.html#random-generation) and [uuid.uuid4()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/uuid.html?highlight=uuid4#uuid.uuid4) and [os.urandom()](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.urandom) and a few other functions.
Historically, many people have been tricked into using a so-called ["random"](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html) function that is completely inappropriate for generating one-time pads, such as [RANDU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANDU).

### Your choice

You must choose some base. Either base 10 (decimal) or base 26 (alphabetic) work great for one time pads.
In principle, you could pick any base.
However -- as you have seen -- mixing both CT-46 (i.e., decimal) and also base-26 creates an incompatible mixture that doesn't work.
It only *seems* to work for the first letter because another bug involving operator precedence cancels out that problem in the first letter, as described by Ilmari Karonen. Fix that bug by adding more parenthesis: change

```
plaintext = ciphertext-key%26
```

to

```
plaintext = (ciphertext-key)%26
```

When two bugs cancel each other out like this -- that can be difficult to fix.

You might consider starting by writing one program to do alphabetic one-time pads (this is easier to write and debug), and once that is working, re-using most of that program in a separate program that uses CT-46 encoding (which adds some complexity).

I'm mystified as to how the value "48" got into your key?

### Alphabetic

```
 t  a  v  a  r  e  s  : plaintext
20  1 22  1 18  5 19  : standard A-->1, B-->2, C-->3, etc. encoding.
48  5  3  1  9  3 25  : key ("48"? where did that come from?)
68  6 25  2 27  8 44  : sum
16  6 25  2  1  8 18  : sum modulo 26
 p  f  y  b  a  h  r  : standard A-->1, B-->2, C-->3, etc. encoding.  
 pfyba  ahr           : ciphertext
```

### straddling checkerboard

On a hand calculator, modulo 10 is much easier than modulo 26:
I simply read last digit -- the digit in the one's place.
I ignore all the other digits -- the digit in the 10's place, the 100's place, etc.
(Modulo with negative numbers is a bit more complex).

encoding:

```
 t    a  v  a  r  e  s  : plaintext
 83   1 85  1  6  2 82  : CT-46 chart encoding.
 8  3 1 8 5 1  6 2  8 2 : split into individual digits
 4  8 5 0 3 1  9 3  2 5 : key (also individual digits)
12 11 6 8 8 2 15 5 10 7 : sum
 2  1 6 8 8 2  5 5  0 7 : sum modulo 10
 21688 25507            : ciphertext
```

decoding:

```
 21688 25507            : ciphertext
 2  1  6  8  8  2  5  5  0  7 : split into individual digits
 4  8  5  0  3  1  9  3  2  5 : key (also individual digits)
-2 -7  1  8  5  1 -4  2 -2  2 : difference
 8  3  1  8  5  1  6  2  8  2 : difference modulo 10
  83   1   85   1  6  2   82  : pair up in the CT-46 style
  T    A   V    A  R  E   S   : CT-46 chart decoding
```

Answer (score 3):

In modular calculations such as this, the divisor (in your case 26) must be at least the size of your character code space. Your code space is 46 characters, so that is not going to work.

Any output of the modular calculation will be less than the divisor, so you will never get 83 for x mod 26, it is not going to happen. For a 46 character code space, 46 is the appropriate divisor.

Also the code space for your message characters is inconsistent, 06 codes to both "6" and "R". 92 will also code the same as 00 mod 46, so your code book values will never work. They must all be unique mod 46.

You have even more problems with your key and ciphertext. There was no modular calculation in generating your ciphertext, or all values would be less than 26. I also have no idea how you got 83+48=105, and 48 is once again outside the code space.

Comment: ok i see what when wrong with the code space I was using        A = 0 B = 1 C = 2 ....... using mod 26 when i wrote the script

Comment: So what do i need to change the codebook and what else ?

Comment: @user13120 : $\:$ You need to put in parentheses. $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 2):

Your calculator is correct: $$105-48 = 57 \equiv 5 \pmod{26}.$$

Your Python code, however, calculates `105 - 48 % 26`, which Python, due to its [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) rules, evaluates as `105 - (48 % 26)` = `105 - 22` = `83`.

To get the correct remainder modulo 26, you need to add parentheses to your Python code so that it reads `(105 - 48) % 26` instead.  This will return the correct answer `5`.
In any case, it's obvious that 83 *cannot* be the correct remainder modulo 26, since it is greater than the modulus!

Of course, to get your encryption working (in the sense that it can be correctly decrypted), you'll also need to fix the issue pointed out by Richie Frame: if your alphabet has 46 symbols, you'll need to use a modulus of *at least* 46 in your modular arithmetic, or you'll end up encrypting several plaintext symbols to the same ciphertext symbol.